# I've created a trigger on Employee_Table which updates Department_Table column based on Dept_ID of inserted row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I've created a trigger on Employee_Table which updates Department_Table column based on Dept_ID of inserted row. Now I only wanted to enter the cursor if my "inserted" table of trigger have rows with multiple Dept_ID & I'm unable to find any answer on the internet. Any lead would be appreciated.

```
USE [Test_DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Employee_Table_ForInsert]
ON [dbo].[Employee_Table]
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Employee_Backup (Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Emp_Address, Comp_ID, Dept_ID)
SELECT Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Emp_Address, Comp_ID, Dept_ID
FROM inserted

DECLARE Cursor_Inserted CURSOR FOR
SELECT * FROM inserted
OPEN Cursor_Inserted
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @EmpName NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @EmpAdd NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @CompID INT
DECLARE @DeptID INT

FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_Inserted INTO @ID,@EmpName,@EmpAdd,@CompID,@DeptID
WHILE(@@Fetch_Status=0)
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Old_ID INT
    SELECT @Old_ID = (SELECT COUNT(Emp_ID) FROM Employee_Table 
    WHERE Dept_ID = @DeptID)

    UPDATE Department_Table SET Emp_Count =
    (@Old_ID) WHERE Dept_ID = @DeptID

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_Inserted INTO @ID,@EmpName,@EmpAdd,@CompID,@DeptID

END
CLOSE Cursor_Inserted
DEALLOCATE Cursor_Inserted

END
```

Comment: If you *must* store the employee count (it's usually best not to, unless you've demonstrated a performance issue with just computing it during retrieval), have you considered using an indexed view instead, that will automatically perform the maintenance? (And thus not offer any opportunity for the stored, computed value to get out of sync)

Comment: How do you write an `if` statement to implement "with multiple Dept_ID & I'm unable to find any answer on the internet"? Would you really want a trigger to go surfing the Internet while blocking other table updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sql, Cursors should only be used as a last resort, as they are very inefficient.
I don't really understand the reason you want a copy of all inserted data in `Employee_Backup`, nor do I understand the reason you want to keep the number of employees in a specific department in the department table where you can simlpy select the count when needed, but I can offer a better trigger then the one you currently have:

```
USE [Test_DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Employee_Table_ForInsert]
ON [dbo].[Employee_Table]
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Employee_Backup (Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Emp_Address, Comp_ID, Dept_ID)
SELECT Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Emp_Address, Comp_ID, Dept_ID
FROM inserted

UPDATE D
SET Emp_Count = E.Emp_Count
FROM Department_Table D
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Dept_ID, COUNT(Emp_ID) Emp_Count
    FROM Employee_Table
    GROUP BY Dept_ID
) E ON(D.Dept_ID = E.Dept_ID)


END
```

Comment: @peter There's no such need actually, I'm just learning how to use Cursor. That inner join also worked fine & I think for big data sets, this inner join will give the result more quickly.